# Do services have hwnd?

Tags: vb.net, service, hwnd

I wrote a service in VB.NET, however it calls a DLL which requires a HWND. Is there a way to get the hwnd of a service, if it exists at all?

Also, just a quick question, what is the difference between a service and a program run as SYSTEM by the task scheduler.

Comment: You can also use [NativeWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.aspx) if you need a managed version of CreateWindow.

Answer (score 0):

Services do not run in windows, hence they don't have a hWnd. Maybe you can pass 0 as a value? What is the DLL supposed to do with the hWnd?

Comment: It does something like this:  struct cengine *engine = (struct cengine *)handle;

Answer (score 0):

HWND is a window handle. If Alexander's solution doesn't work you could have your service create a window ([CreateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Casting HWND to some other struct is generally not a good idea (See comment to Alexander's answer), are you sure it wants a window handle?

Comment: What is difference between a service and a program run as SYSTEM by the task scheduler?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) programs run by the taskscheduler run in a different Session than services. But they're both processes running somewhere that's protected from the user...

Answer (score 0):

A service is a program, too, it just (usually) runs without being seen in a window. So usually a service won't have a window handle.

If your program wants to create a window, you can, but it will not be visible if it is run as a service.